# Cloudbees virtual host versus tomcat context path

Tags: tomcat, cloudbees

I have a web app that I run locally in tomcat and which I have also deployed to Cloudbees. However, I am having some problems with cloudbees using a virtual host versus my local tomcat using a context path.

I access my local tomcat app via

- `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC`

In cloudbees, I access it via

- http://springmvc.shaunabram.cloudbees.net

So far so good, but the problem is when I try to do a submit. Locally, this submits successfully to

- `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/HelloWorld`

But on cloudbees, it tries (and fails) to submit to

- `http://springmvc.shaunabram.cloudbees.net/SpringMVC/HelloWorld`

If I manually modify the browser URL to

- `http://springmvc.shaunabram.cloudbees.net/HelloWorld`

it all works fine.

I saw a similar problem [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957578/app-runs-locally-but-returns-404-running-on-cloudbees), but the suggested solution was to

1. update the web.xml to use the prefix path (e.g. I think
   /SpringMVC in my case), but this would break my local tomcat version, or
2. deploy the app as an EAR file with an application.xml - but
       migrating to an EE container like tomcat EE or JBoss will be a much
       bigger task.

I had thought the solution might be to use the CloudBees Web Configuration File to somehow configure the app to use (something like) `http://springmvc.shaunabram.cloudbees.net/SpringMVC` as my base url, but I can't see any examples of that (all CloudBees Web Configuration File examples seem to be used for environment specific DataSources).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web application should never use absolute path and always build URL using ServletContext.getContextPath(). I wonder you hit this issue, assuming you use SpringMVC that handles this for you.

Or maybe you hard-coded some resources path, but should use  to generate the adequate path, or a scriptlet to append context Path :

```
<c:url value="/style.css" var="url" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${url}" type="text/css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style.css" type="text/css">
```

see also [Spring MVC Request URLs in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970115/spring-mvc-request-urls-in-jsp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and link) Nicolas. swashbuck1r's answer was also useful.
As advised, the solution was simply changing my form action from 
<FORM ACTION="/SpringMVC/HelloWorld">
to
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<FORM ACTION="${contextPath}/HelloWorld">

Many thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees runs your applications using a ROOT context path [/]. You have at least two options to make your app work in both your local environment and the Cloud environment:

- Run your app locally using a ROOT context (by deploying the app to
  webapps/ROOT or webapos/ROOT.war)
- Change the URL used to generate your form to construct the form's action path using 
  request.getContextPath()