# Why is my WebApp callded at [myDomain]/_stax/status?

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I'm having a Play-2.0.4-WebApp running at Cloudbees and it gets called (about once a day) from a Cloudbees internal Server (`10.204.X.Y`) on `http://myDomain/_stax/status`.

But as this route doesn't exist in my Play-App, it obviously throws me a `RouteNotFound`-Exception.

I've searched the web so far for "_stax/status" and found nothing but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957578/app-runs-locally-but-returns-404-running-on-cloudbees). But it didn't bring me further.

I still have the two questions:

- Why do they call it?
- What do they expect to get as a response?

Comment: I did hear about this, but I think it is (or will be) some kind of "ping" to your app used for monitoring. I assume that you should return a HTTP 200 code to say that your app is alive, or maybe 404 is enough because it will say that the app is running (vs 50x code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you perhaps guessed, this is simply a liveness check for the application. URLs in the `_stax/*` namespace are not supposed to be handled by the user’s application but rather by the ClickStack, i.e. adapter between the general application framework (here Play2) and the CloudBees monitoring and management infrastructure.

I am not sure why in this case this request is being passed on to your application’s routing logic rather than being handled at a lower level. You need not make any changes to your application to handle it—the details are subject to change anyway—but if the access log mention is irritating (or you suspect it is causing some other issue) just open a support ticket.